# GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC and GC_FOR_MALLOC log messages are generated every second

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using libgdx for an application but Logcat is generating `GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC` and `GC_FOR_MALLOC` log messages per second.

Is this normal? I don't think this kind of large number of logs are good for the system. Is there any way to depress these messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the garbage collection system. It only puts those messages out if you are connected to LogCat otherwise you shouldn't worry too much about them.